# Проблема с переменной или функцией

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli, функции

Это **body.php** Для вывода всех строчек с масива отвечает функция getPosts, она же и задает в ссылке id

```
<?require_once ("functions/bd_connect.php");?>
<?require_once ("functions/bd_matches.php");?>


<section class="box" style="background-color:#edf3fe; width: 850px; height: 100%; padding-left: 23px; float: left">
<div class="title" style="background: url(img/my_trades.png) no-repeat; text-transform: none;">
Trades</div>

</section>

<section class="box" style="background-color:#d7d7d7; width: 850px; height: 100%; padding-left: 23px; padding-right: 23px; float:right">
<div class="title" style="background: url(img/my_bets.png) no-repeat;text-transform: none; ">
Bets</div>
<article class="standard" id="bets" style="margin-top: 40px;">



<?$posts = getPosts();?> <!-- Главные строки !-->
<? foreach($posts as $post): ?> <!-- Главные строки !-->
<div class="matchmain">

<div class="matchheader">
  <div class="whenm">
   <?=$post['time']?>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(209, 33, 33);"/>
  </div>
  <div class="eventm"><?=$post['event']?></div>
</div>
<div class="match" style="background-image:url('img/event/<?=$post['event']?>.jpg');">
<div class="matchleft">

<a href="/match.php?m=<? echo $post['id']?>">
<div style="width: 45%; float: left; text-align: right;">
<div class="team" style="float: right;"><img src="img/teams/<?=$post['team 1']?>.jpg"></img></div>
<div class="teamtext">
<b><?=$post['team 1']?></b>
<br/>
<i>19%</i>
</div>
</div>
<div style="width: 10%; float: left; text-align: center; margin-top: 0.6em; ">
<span class="format"><?=$post['bon']?></span>
<br/>
vs
 </div>
 <div style="width: 45%; float: left; text-align: left;">
<div class="team" style="float: left;";><img src="img/teams/<?=$post['team 2']?>.jpg"></img></div>
<div class="teamtext">
<b><?=$post['team 2']?></b>
<br/>
<i>81%</i>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div
</div>
<? endforeach; ?> <!-- Главные строки !-->


 </article>

</section>
```

Это **match.php**

```
<?
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'my_site_1');
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo 'Ошибка подключения к БД ('.mysqli_connect_errno().'): '.mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} ?>


<?require_once ("functions/bd_matches.php");?>
<body>


<?$matches = getMatch(strip_tags($_GET['m']));
foreach($matches as $match)
{
    echo $match['team 1'];
}


?>
```

А это **bd_matches.php**

```
<?
function getPosts() {

    global $link;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `matches` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 21";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $posts = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, 1) ;
    return $posts;
}


function getMatch($m) {
  global $link;
  if($m)
  {
    echo 'All is good';
    echo $m;
    $where = "WHERE 'id' = ".$m;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `matches` $where ORDER BY 'id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $matches = mysqli_fetch_all($result, 1) ;
    return $matches;
   }
}





?>
```

А это **База данных**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Хост: 127.0.0.1
-- Время создания: Янв 13 2017 г., 22:38
-- Версия сервера: 5.5.25
-- Версия PHP: 5.3.13

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- База данных: `my_site_1`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `matches`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `matches` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bon` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `team 1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team 2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=41 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `matches`
--

INSERT INTO `matches` (`id`, `event`, `bon`, `team 1`, `team 2`, `time`) VALUES
(2, 'DreamHack', 'BO3', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '14:53:00'),
(3, 'Dolphin SEA', 'BO1', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '18:13:00'),
(8, 'Dolphin SEA', 'BO1', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '18:13:00'),
(11, 'Dolphin SEA', 'BO1', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '18:13:00'),
(13, 'Dolphin SEA', 'BO1', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '18:13:00'),
(14, 'Dolphin SEA', 'BO1', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '18:13:00'),
(16, 'Dolphin SEA', 'BO1', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '18:13:00'),
(19, 'ESEA', 'BO1', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '18:13:00'),
(22, 'DreamHack', 'BO3', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '14:53:00'),
(23, 'ESEA', 'BO1', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '18:13:00'),
(24, 'DreamHack', 'BO3', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '14:53:00'),
(25, 'DreamHack', 'BO3', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '14:53:00'),
(26, 'DreamHack', 'BO3', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '14:53:00'),
(27, 'DreamHack', 'BO3', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '14:53:00'),
(28, 'DreamHack', 'BO3', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '14:53:00'),
(29, 'DreamHack', 'BO3', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '14:53:00'),
(30, 'DreamHack', 'BO3', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '14:53:00'),
(31, 'King of Nordic', 'BO1', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '18:13:00'),
(32, 'DreamHack', 'BO3', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '14:53:00'),
(33, 'King of Nordic', 'BO1', 'G2', 'Fnatic', '18:13:00'),
(34, 'ESEA', 'BO3', 'Fnatic', 'G2', '14:53:00'),
(35, 'ESEA', 'BO1', 'Na''Vi', 'VP', '14:53:00'),
(36, 'WESG', 'BO3', 'Selfless', 'G2', '17:55:00'),
(37, 'ESEA', 'BO7', 'Epsilon', 'LDLC', '14:24:00'),
(38, 'King of Nordic', 'BO1', 'Fnatic', 'Rogue', '13:33:00'),
(39, 'ESEA', 'BO5', 'Na''Vi', 'VP', '16:23:00');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: так у вас все правельно работает, вы же не выводите результат селекта к базе данных

Comment: а как вывести ?

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
print_r($result);

Comment: А чтоб не массивом?

Comment: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row;
}

Comment: Я исправил вопрос, слегка не заметил :) Проверь сейчас код

Comment: Вот блин, видимо некакие, кроме как вывести All is good и id

Comment: Слушай, а не поможешь, как все сделать? я уже долго бьюсь над этим

Comment: надо передавать значение в адресной строке  ?m=vashi-dannie

Comment: Аа `?m` у меня = `<?=post['id']?>`

Comment: и на исходе получается, к примеру `?m=25` или `?m=4` смотря на какую ссылку кликну

Comment: Вам предлагаю подучить пхп, так как все что вы написали полный бред, ничего не работает, начните с самого простого.

к примеру передавать m . и отпечатать его в скрипте echo $_GET['m'];

Comment: ну получилось отпечатать m?

Comment: Да я видео уроки смотрю, ей богу помоги

Comment: Клянусь, я перехожу на ссылку и она выдает тот ид, в каком месте она в таблице, но вот чтоб она еще все значения выдавала из той же колонки в таблице у меня не получается сделать

Comment: Ладно, я отчаялся, думаю ты мне не исправишь код...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getMatch($m) {
        global $link;
  if($m)
  {
    echo 'All is good<br>';
    echo $m;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM matches WHERE id=$m";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $matches = mysqli_fetch_all($result, 1) ;
    return $matches;
   }
}
$matches = getMatch(strip_tags($_GET['m']));
//print_r($matches);
foreach($matches as $match)
{
   echo $match['event'] . " : " . $match['bon'] . " : " . $match['team 1'];
}
```